# Mistake in CS50 Readability project with only 1 input, all others work

Tags: c, cs50

I seem to have made a mistake in my code but I can't find it.
All reading grades give me the correct grade, except for grade 7 which results in grade 8.
I assume it is a rounding error of some sort?

I tested the following piece of code with and without the ***round()*** in the last function.
Without it most of the grade levels are off, with the ***round()*** in there I only get an mistake a the grade7 level.

Where is my mistake?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

//Prototypes
int count_letters(string text);
int count_words(string text);
int count_sentences(string text);
int get_score (string text);

//Main function
int main(void)
{
    //Get user input
    string text = get_string("Text: ");

    //Grade user text
    int i = get_score(text);

    if(i < 1)
    {
        printf("Before Grade 1\n");
    }
    else if (i > 1 && i < 16)
    {
        printf("Grade %i\n", i);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Grade 16+\n");
    }

}



// Extra functions

int count_letters(string text)
{
    // variables
    int letters = strlen(text);
    int total_letters = 0;
    int characters = 0;

    // Loop through text and count all non-letters
    for(int i = 0; i < letters; i++)
    {
        if((text[i] < 65 || text[i] > 95) && (text[i] < 97 || text[i] > 122))
        {
            characters++;
        }

    }

    // substract all non-letters from total chars and return.
    total_letters = letters - characters;
    return total_letters;
}

int count_words(string text)
{
    // variables
    int letters = strlen(text);
    int spaces = 1;

    // Loop through text and count all spaces
    for(int i = 0; i < letters; i++)
    {
        if(text[i] == ' ')
        {
            spaces++;
        }

    }

  return spaces;
}

int count_sentences(string text)
{
     // variables
    int letters = strlen(text);
    int sentence = 0;

    // Loop through text and count all sentences
    for(int i = 0; i < letters; i++)
    {
        if(text[i] == 46 || text[i] == 33 || text[i] == 63)
        {
            sentence++;
        }

    }

  return sentence;
}

int get_score (string text)
{
    //variables
    int letters = count_letters(text);
    int words = count_words(text);
    int sentence = count_sentences(text);
    float index = 0;

    // letters divided by words * 100
    float L = 100 * letters / words;
    // sentences divided by words *100
    float S = 100 * sentence / words;

    index = round(0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8);

    return index;

}
```

Comment: `float L = 100 * letters / words;` This uses integer division and only afterwards converts to `float`. Same for `S`. You need to cast one of the operands to `float` or `double` to avoid this. Or use `100.0 * ....`

Comment: You have handled `if(i < 1)` and `else if (i > 1 && i < 16)`, so if input is `1` then your programs outputs _Grade 16+_

Comment: Don't ever hard code numbers like `65`, `95`, `97`, and `122`.  Write those as (what I believe you intend) `'A'`, `'_'`, `'a'`, and `'z'` and it is immediatly clear that you probably meant `90` instead of `97`.

Comment: I have fixed the things you said and now it works!
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if((text[i] < 65 || text[i] > 95) && (text[i] < 97 || text[i] > 122))` is almost certainly a bug.  You probably meant to be implementing `isalpha`, but you did it incorrectly.  You meant to write:

`if((text[i] < 'A' || text[i] > 'Z') && (text[i] < 'a' || text[i] > 'z'))`, which would have avoided the typo in which `95` was used instead of `90`.  Instead of this, though, you should just use the standard library and write:

```
if( ! isalpha(text[i]) ) ...
```

Using literals like `'A'` instead of the magic number `65` makes the code more readable and helps avoid trivial mistakes like this.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. Will do this from now on.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few issues with your code:

1. As @IrAM has mentioned in a comment, your `if` does not handle a score of `1`. Moreover, you can simplify your `if` checks if you start from the other end, i.e. first check for greater than 16:

```
int main(void)
{
    //Get user input
    string text = get_string("Text: ");

    //Grade user text
    int i = get_score(text);

    if(i > 16)
    {     
        printf("Grade 16+\n");
    }
    else if (i > 0)
    {
        printf("Grade %i\n", i);
    }
    else
    {
       printf("Before Grade 1\n");
    }
}
```

2. As @Gerhardh mentions, you are dividing two integers which forces the result to be an integer too. If at least one of the operands is casted to a `float`, the result is type-promoted to a float:

```
    // letters divided by words * 100
    float L = 100 * (float) letters / words;
    // sentences divided by words *100
    float S = 100 * (float) sentence / words;
```

#### Optimizations

You have three different functions for counting words, sentences and letters. Why three loops when you can do it in one loop? Plus an additional iteration for `strlen()` in each function. Write a `Count` struct like this:

```
struct Count 
{
    int letters;
    int words;
    int sentences;
    int length;
};
```

Then have one function that returns this struct. Like @WilliamPursell mentions, using character literals instead of ASCII values makes code much more readable:

```
Count get_count(string text) 
{
    Count result = {0, 1, 0, 0};

    result.length = strlen(text);
    int characters = 0;
    

    // Loop through text and count all non-letters
    for(int i = 0; i < count.length; i++)
    {
        if((text[i] < 'A' || text[i] > 'Z') && (text[i] < 'a' || text[i] > 'z'))
        {
            characters++;
        }
        if(text[i] == ' ')
        {
            result.words++;
        }
        if(text[i] == '.' || text[i] == '!' || text[i] == '?')
        {
            result.sentences++;
        }

    }

    // subtract all non-letters from total chars and return.
    count.letters = count.length - characters;
    
    return result;

}
```

This is what `get_score()` will change to:

```
int get_score (string text)
{
    //variables
    Count result = get_count(text);
    float index = 0;

    // letters divided by words * 100
    float L = 100 * (float) result.letters / result.words;
    // sentences divided by words *100
    float S = 100 * (float) result.sentences / result.words;

    index = round(0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8);

    return index;

}
```

Side Note: A `'.'` may always not necessarily mean the end of a sentence. It has [other](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_stop) meanings like in an acronym or as ellipsis.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
The course did not talk about Structs yet, now I have started the next section they have. 
My plan is to now go back to previous projects and see how I can improve with the new things I learned.
Thank you!